# How to get crontab to run when backup requires a password

Tags: linux, bash, backup, cron, postgresql

I am running a script to backup my postgres database on Debian. I am basically running exactly this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux

Now I have everything working fine when I run it manually but I have to enter a password and I want to make a crontab that runs this backup script every night. Is there any way to make the crontab automatically fill the prompt with the correct password or do you know how I can put something like this in my bash script?

Comment: What program or part of the process is actually asking for a password?

Comment: access to the postgres database requires a password

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405127/how-do-i-specify-a-password-to-psql-non-interactively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `.pgpass` file under the home directory of the user who the cron job runs as.

See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html).